Why doesn't the Coanda effect pull fluid from the center of the streamline?
As explained nicely in this answer, the Coanda effect will pull air from the surrounding air outside of the streamline. This picture shows it nicely :

So my question is what stops the low pressure created or the 'cavity' from taking said fluid from the inside streamline?

I also can quote the answer I provided :

That fluid that is removed has to be replaced. It sucks in fluid laterally from farther away from the jet

(if that didn't make sense, the answer I linked should clear things up)
Why does it suck in laterally? Why doesn't it also pull fluid from inside the streamline? The force of pressure / a cavity needing to be filled doesn't just act in one direction.
(The streamline meaning the jet pictured above)

What do you mean by "the streamline"? The jet, perhaps?

Yes the jet that's correct. (will edit that in)

A possible explanation is because this effect happens all over the streamline, it only will pull from outside. Like if you have a ball and if you pull only on one side it’ll move in that direction, but if you pull on all sides it’ll stay still. Not sure how this would work with air as it’s compressible.

I don't understand what your question is: Why doesn't it also pull fluid from inside the streamline?
